Ephemeral checkout of branch that is automatically delete/garbage collected when switched away from
Situation: review branch origin/feature_A:
$ cd review
$ git switch feature_A   #  <-- this creates a local branch feature_a tracking origin/feature_A
$ git switch feature_B   # Now I have forgotten about feature_A
$ git branch -D feature_A   # I need to do this command manually :(

When reviewing work from a colleague I like to switch to that branch and investigate the code in my git worktree (to be able to run CLI commands, tests and use my editor). After I'm done reviewing I usually switch back to my own working branch - but I forget to delete my local copy of the branch. After a year I have ~30 branches that I don't care about anymore. Can I get these automatically cleaned up somehow?

You could read the output of git remote prune origin to inform the input of git branch -D? Git probably doesn't have an automatic way of doing this, because it doesn't know whether you would like to keep the local copy or not. (I usually do!)

Yes, this can be achieved by switching to origin/feature_A with detached HEAD:
git switch -d origin/feature_A

this will prevent a local branch from being created, and the remote branch can be pruned with fetch -p after it has been removed on the remote.

oooooo. I love it when I'm wrong

Love this git feature... @evolutionxbox I've been talking about not needing local branches for things like master/main for a while already... have you missed that "speech" all these years?

I upvoted.. but it's a duplicate..... let me mark it as such.

@eftshift0 speech??? (my favourite git talk is "git for ages 4 and up)
